# how to load a .dvb file in autocad - Unknown command autocad - vba

Tags: vba, autocad, autolisp

I write a example vba macro like this:

```
Public Sub main()
   MsgBox "hi"
End Sub
```

I stored it at :

F:/gr/masoud.dvb

I write a lsp file like this masoud.lsp:

```
(defun s::startup()
  (command "-vbaload" "F:/gr/masoud.dvb")
  (setvar "cmdecho" 0)
  (defun c:MAINGR() 
  (command "vbarun" "masoud.main")
)
```

I load this macro at autocad:

1. run CUI command
2. LISP Files
3. load masoud.lsp

but when I run this command:

MAINGR

it says:

```
Unknown command MAINGR
```

Answer (score 0):

At first look I would say that you have missed a closing parentheses `)` in your last `defun`.
I didn't check the example code and there is a couple of things that I would make differently, but please check it and let me know if you need any further help.